# ClassNoDefFoundError while running a junit test which is instrumented using TPTP probekit agent

Tags: junit, noclassdeffounderror, instrumentation, quickfix, eclipse-tptp

I've been dealing with this error message for a while now and nobody has been able to help me...

I am trying to probe a java application using the standalone TPTP probekit agent with the following linux command:

> java '-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=standalone;ProbekitAgent:ext-pk-BCILibraryName=BCIEngProbe,ext-pk-probescript=ome/anis/qf-t/core/probe/testProbe.probescript' junit.textui.TestRunner quickfix.test.acceptance.AcceptanceTestSuite

My application is actually a junit testcase from the Quickfixj package (quickfixj.org)...

Running the above command, the probing starts and I am able to see the runtime traces. However, at some point during execution I am getting the runtime exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testProbe_probe$Probe_0

```
25-Jan-2012 10:25:11 AM quickfix.test.acceptance.ATServer run
SEVERE: error in AT server
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testProbe_probe$Probe_0
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.<init>(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:233)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:123)
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.load(DataDictionary.java:906)
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.read(DataDictionary.java:893)
    at quickfix.DataDictionary.<init>(DataDictionary.java:109)
    at quickfix.DefaultSessionFactory.getDataDictionary(DefaultSessionFactory.java:325)
    at quickfix.DefaultSessionFactory.createDataDictionary(DefaultSessionFactory.java:219)
    at quickfix.DefaultSessionFactory.processFixtDataDictionaries(DefaultSessionFactory.java:258)
    at quickfix.DefaultSessionFactory.create(DefaultSessionFactory.java:113)
    at quickfix.mina.acceptor.AbstractSocketAcceptor.createSessions(AbstractSocketAcceptor.java:242)
    at quickfix.mina.acceptor.AbstractSocketAcceptor.startAcceptingConnections(AbstractSocketAcceptor.java:99)
    at quickfix.SocketAcceptor.initialize(SocketAcceptor.java:66)
    at quickfix.SocketAcceptor.start(SocketAcceptor.java:59)
    at quickfix.test.acceptance.ATServer.run(ATServer.java:193)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)**
```

which states that my probe file is missing. But this file has been needed in the first place to print the traces!!???.....

Well, here are some facts:

- I am able to probe other applications, including a simple junit test:

  > java '-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=standalone;ProbekitAgent:ext-pk-BCILibraryName=BCIEngProbe,ext-pk-probescript=ome/anis/qf-t/core/probe/testProbe.probescript' junit.textui.TestRunner quickfix.test.acceptance.AnisJUnitTestExample
- I am able to run the quickfix.test.acceptance.AcceptanceTestSuite using junit (no probing):

  > java junit.textui.TestRunner quickfix.test.acceptance.AcceptanceTestSuite
- I have set the path to testProbe_probe$Probe_0 in CLASSPATH
- I have called the System.getenv("CLASSPATH") from within my testcase and the CLASSPATH seems to be fine
- My testcase deals with threads, sockets, etc

And my system configuration is:

```
-os: ubuntu 10.04-64bit (on VirtualBox!)

-java version "1.6.0_24"

-junit: junit-4.10.jar

-TPTP agent controller: agntctrl.linux_em64t-TPTP-4.7.2
```

Any ideas??

Thanks,
Anis